# Disabling (or overriding) a css file from contrib module's library

Tags: theming, 9

I am using admin_toolbar module and I would like to override the path to a logo file that is by default provided by one of this module's CSS file.

I found information that I can achieve this with *libraries-override* in my theme.info.yml file.

The problem is that the file seems to be still loaded when I check the page source.

The file that defines the path to a logo file is located in:

> /modules/contrib/admin_toolbar/admin_toolbar_tools/css/tools.css

And my theme.info.yml file looks like this:

```
name: Custom Olivero Theme
type: theme
description: 'Custom Olivero Theme.'
package: Custom Themes
core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9
libraries:
  - custom_olivero/global-styling
base theme: olivero
libraries-override:
  admin_toolbar_tools/toolbar.icon:
    css:
      theme:
        /modules/contrib/admin_toolbar/admin_toolbar_tools/css/tools.css: false
```

Can you please share any suggestions on what am I doing wrong or, if this approach is not following the good Drupal practices, suggest what is the better way of achieving the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of the [admin_toolbar_tools.libraries.yml](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/admin_toolbar/-/blob/3.x/admin_toolbar_tools/admin_toolbar_tools.libraries.yml) file is the following.

```yaml
toolbar.icon:
  css:
    theme:
      css/tools.css: {}
```

You remove that file with the following override.

```yaml
libraries-override:
  admin_toolbar_tools/toolbar.icon:
    css:
      theme:
        css/tools.css: false
```

You do not need to use the full file path, but the path used in the .libraries.yml file for that module.

Comment: Thank you. Changing the path worked!